# DNN - add a pane to DDR menu item

Tags: xslt, dotnetnuke, ddrmenu

Is there a way to add a pane to the DDR menu template in DNN?
I tryed like this, but the asp controls dont get rendered:

```
<ul class="navigation">
    [*>NODE-TOP]
</ul>

    [>NODE-TOP]
        <li class="[?NODE]hasDropdown [/?][?SELECTED]active[/?]">
        [?ENABLED]
            <a href="[=URL]" target="[=TARGET]">
                <span>[=TEXT]</span> [?NODE][/?] 
            </a>
        [?ELSE]
            <a href="#" target="[=TARGET]">
                <span>[=TEXT]</span> [?NODE][/?]
            </a>
        [/?]

 <div class="pane" id="menu[=ID]Pane" runat="server"></div>

        [?NODE]

            <ul class="sub">
                [*>NODE]
            </ul>
        [/?]

        </li>
    [/>]
```

Is there a workaround to place a "dynamic" pane with "menu item id" as name in the ddr menu?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to do that inside a DDRMenu token template. It is a component that renders its own thing (DDRMenu tokens). By the time it leaves its resulting HTML at it's insertion point in the skin file, the runat-server is too late.

I can't think of a way to accomplish what you are ultimately trying to do. Hopefully someone else has some ideas. Cheers!